# How to specify the thickness of edge in dotfile?

Tags: graphviz

I'd like set the thickness of edge in dot file, but could not find the corresponding attribute, anyone know that ? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably looking for [`penwidth`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/penwidth/):

> Specifies the width of the pen, in points, used to draw lines and
> curves, including the boundaries of edges and clusters. The value is
> inherited by subclusters. It has no effect on text.
>
> Previous to 31 January 2008, the effect of penwidth=W was achieved by
> including setlinewidth(W) as part of a style specification. If both
> are used, penwidth will be used.